# GTM Google analytics on localhost (127.0.0.1) application not being tracked

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, chromium, gtag.js

I have a software with chromium browser embed and I'm using GTM Google analytics to track users access, pageviews requests are being made, I can see them on network tab, but I can't see them inside Google analytics dashboard.

I thought that the reason could be something with this localhost (127.0.0.1), one small detail is that everytime user open the software the localhost application will run on a different port, i.e.: 127.0.0.1:55437 then if it is opened again will be for example 127.0.0.1:55874.

Am I missing something? Maybe some config inside GTM or GA panel?